# mysql select query on two tables in specific order

Tags: mysql

I have two tables 
 questions table like below 
[image: questions content]
 and answers table like below
[image]

every question has multiple answers
How can I make query to return the result as below table 
[image]

Comment: the `Q&A` column of `question_answers_tb` contains values from two columns combined and so does the `ID` column. From a relational standpoint that is just wrong.

Comment: @Relfor That is called 'UNION'. But what is really a concern here is that in the current structure, there is no way to tie the groupings of answers together.

Comment: @tuespetre sure i will use the term relational without knowing what'UNION' is ;P im not getting that relational feel, this is subjective however.

Comment: Oh no, I know what you mean about not getting that feel.

Answer (score 3):

You have to order by two columns - `q_id` and `ans_id`. Since in `question_tb` there is no `ans_id` field you can put `0` instead.

```
select t.id, t.q_content from
(
  select q_id, q_content, 0 k, q_id id from question_tb
  union 
  select ans_q_id, ans_content, ans_id, ans_id from answer_tb
) t  order by t.q_id, t.k
```

Answer (score -1):

Hmmm.. I think you need to re-think your structure a bit:  the last table (or query result) needs a column to designate which is the question, and which are the answers, and also to indicate the *correct* answer.

Also, I assume that each set of questions (and answers) will be tied to a particular user, so you will need a user_key in the answer table, as well.

```
 SELECT Q.q_content          AS question,
        ANS.ans_content      AS answer,
        ANS.is_correct,
        ANS.user_id,
   FROM Question_TB Q
        INNER JOIN tb_answer ANS
          ON ANS.ans_q_id = Q.q_id
        ORDER BY ANS.user_id, Q.q_id
```